# Ucanaccess fails on non-standard column name

Tags: java, spring-boot, ucanaccess

I'm accesing a .mdb file with a Spring app. Unfortunately the legacy .mdb has a column with name `E-MAIL` and I cannot get access to this column (witout this column all works fine):

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect

@Entity
public class Contact implements Serializable {

    @Id
    long id;

    @Column(length = 50, name = "NOMBRE")
    String name;

    @Column(length = 30, name = "TELÉFONO")
    String phone;

    @Column(length = 50, name = "E-MAIL")
    String email;
```

I tested diferent things with no success:

```
     spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true

     @Column(length = 50, name = "E\\-MAIL")

     @Column(length = 50, name = "'E-MAIL'")
```

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unknown token: contact0_.
>   in statement [select contact0_.'id' as id1_0_, ..., contact0_.'e-mail'
>   as e4_0_, ...

*EDIT1:*

Spring's settings:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:ucanaccess://./ed.mdb;jackcessOpener=my.package.CryptCodecOpener
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=*******
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver

spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

spring.jpa.show-sql=false

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

Comment: So which JDBC Driver are you using to access your .mdb? And why HSQLDialect?

Comment: It seems to complain about `contact0_` and not the e-mail field.

Comment: @Gyro see my update. HSQLDialect I was "told" to use this one for hibernate+ucanaccess.

Comment: @Henry yes, seems hibernate don't get the name `e-mail` ...

Comment: You might have better luck using a dialect for Microsoft SQL Server instead of the HSQLDB dialect.

Comment: @Gord with `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect` runs well. Thank you.